# Deserialize JSON data into any type in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to be able to send any type of data from javascript to C#. Basically, I'm trying to send a JSON object from the Javascript side via an AJAX call which contains this object -

```
AnObject = new Object;
AnObject.value = anyValue;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myURL",
    data: "{ 'myObject':" + JSON.stringify(AnObject) + "}",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

anyValue could be a int, string, array, associative array, date, etc.

on the C# side, I need a class like -

```
public AnyClass {
    DataType(?) value;
}

public ActionResult acceptData(AnyClass myObject) {
    Here, the data should be deserialized correctly depending on it's type into DataType(?)
}
```

Is this possible? I'm sure there is some generic type in C# that I can use?

Comment: You can deserialize JSON Data using [this](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library. In the link there are some example that exmplain how to use

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko, yes, I use ASP.NET MVC, added the Tag to the question

Answer (score 1):

From a technological standpoint, it's possible. But you'll have to figure out a couple of important details for yourself:

- How do you know what type of object you'll be constructing?
- How will you go about constructing an object of that type? Can you assume the type has a default constructor? Will you use some kind of DI framework?

If you're willing to say that all the objects created really need to be POCO-style objects, this becomes pretty simple:

```
public ActionResult acceptData() {
    Type type = FigureOutWhatTypeToUse();
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    // This allows ASP.NET MVC's model binding to do the dirty work,
    // initializing the properties of your instance based on the submitted
    // parameters.
    TryUpdateModel((dynamic) instance, "myObject"); 
}
```

If you want to pass in an array, define an object type that has a property with an array on it. That way, MVC can pick up on the fact that the property should be an array and bind it accordingly.

PS--this seems more readable and less error prone to me:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ myObject : AnObject }),
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand you. ,NET automatically handles deserialization for us right? So all I have to do is make sure the Value on my AnyClass is a general type that can store any data type. Is that assumption wrong?

Comment: @neuDev33: .NET handles most common deserialization cases correctly, once it knows what object type you're dealing with. If `Value` in the JSON string is `"5"`, does that represent an integer, an enum, or a string in the C# class you're trying to create? Since you can't know at compile-time what type of object you're constructing, you need to devise a way to know this at run-time.

Comment: Ok, so I understand the point you're making. When you say I need to devise a way to know the type at runtime, are you asking me to bypass the default deserialization mechanism of .NET and do something myself? Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: @neuDev33: I provided code that *utilizes* MVC's deserialization, but the one problem that I cannot solve *for you* is how, at run time, you will know what type of object you actually want to produce when this method is called. Perhaps I could help more if you provided more context about what you plan to do with the object once you have it? Surely you can't program any useful code directly against an object whose structure you know nothing about?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how to serialize and desialize Objects from JSon to their correspond types.
It's pretty much simple:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx

Comment: My question is more about how to create an object that can store any type of data, than about serialization and deserialization itself. I think the link you posted covers basics about the latter and not the former.